# What does this expression mean?

Tags: meaning

I have heard this expression so many times 'steaming pile of mediocrity'

Comment: That's not a particularly common phrase. I wouldn't call it an idiom. But the meaning is obvious to me; it refers to something which is sub-par, disappointing, or otherwise "average".

Comment: It is an all too common phrase, so common, in fact, that it is itself a steaming pile of mediocrity.  :)  A "steaming pile" refers to feces. The original phrase is "steaming pile of shit". So "mediocrity" is used euphemistically. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22steaming%20pile%20of%20shit%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I agree with @TimRomano, the expression is astoundingly trite, in the same category as "thinking out of the box," "ASAP," "24/7," and all the rest of the current crop of vulgar platitudes. Please avoid it.

Comment: [I always think of this cartoon when I hear "outside the box"](http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Never-ever-think-outside-the-box-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i8542964_.htm)

Comment: Think of some other material that appears in steaming piles.   Especially, eg, on a street that a horse has just trod.

Answer (score 2):

In short: poop/feces/defecation/garbage/sh**. It's an insult (idiom) used to describe someone or something with comparison to the above. I hope when you heard it it wasn't directed towards you, as the phrase is not commonly used in play.

Answer (score 0):

It's a play on the very insulting and rude "steaming pile of *feces*", which obviously means something very undesirable or unusably bad.

When something is mediocre it is not great, it is not good; but neither is it terribly bad or unsuitable - it's just an ordinary or typical thing you'd find in the middle of a collection of other ordinary and typical things.

By calling something a "steaming pile of mediocrity", they are specifically calling the thing mediocre (so they can't be quoted as saying it's terrible), but the phrase calls to mind the *fecal matter* end of the spectrum of quality, implying the thing is actually worse than mediocre.